# drawing a picture multiple times

Tags: python, indentation

Ok next question I have refers to this code (it draws a line down the picture at the 10th column:

```
def drawLine():
  for y in range(getHeight(pic)):
    pixel = getPixelAt(pic, 9, y)
    setColor(pixel, red)
    show (pic)
```

Ok so I have clearly indented show(pic) one tab too far. So I have it working so I'm not asking how to fix the code. My question is when I put the above code in it draws a line (which seems to be somewhat random) that is approximately 10-50 pixels long at a guess on one copy of the picture. I'm wondering why it does that. Theoretically, shouldn't it be showing a copy of the pic at each iteration?

Comment: What library are you using for all of this?

Comment: My first guess would be that you're just showing the same picture in the exact same place 10-50 times, so the last 9-49 times have no visible effect. Imagine you took 50 identical perfectly thin, perfectly opaque photos prints and stacked them up on your table, then drew a red line on the stack. It would look exactly the same as just using 1 photo.

Comment: @abarnert: If you put that comment into an answer we could upvote it, and then the question wouldn't be categorized as unanswered. I think your answer is right, or as good as we're going to get without further info from the OP.

Comment: @LarsH: I think it might be better to close the question than to answer it, but I added the answer in case others disagree. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks. Yeah, I initially voted to close the Q, then changed my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what library you're using and what these objects are, it's impossible to do more than guess… but one guess seems very plausible.

You appear to be showing the same picture, in the exact same (unspecified) place, 10-50 times (depending on its height). So the last 9-49 times have no visible effect; you're just blitting each pixel over an identical pixel that's already there. (This assumes that you don't have any alpha transparency.)

Meanwhile, you draw a red pixel at (9, 0), then another at (9, 1), and so on all the way up to (9, 10) or (9, 50) or whatever the height of your image is. So, that draws a red line across the picture or next to it.

Imagine you took 50 identical perfectly thin, perfectly opaque photos prints and stacked them up on your table, then drew a red line across or next to the stack. It would look exactly the same as putting one photo print on your table and drawing a red line across or next to it. Which is exactly what you're seeing.